# SetNeedsDisplay having no effect

Tags: swift, uiview, uicontainerview, setneedsdisplay

I am creating a subview in a UIContainerView that is of the class described below. These values are printing correctly to the terminal window but are not actual being shown in the the subview that I am defining. I thought that setNeedsDisplay() should take care of this but nothing ever shows up.

I am creating this subview as `let canvas = Canvas()` and also tried

`canvas.setNeedsDisplay()` which has no effect.

```
class Canvas: UIView {

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

      super.draw(rect)
      guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

      context.setStrokeColor(login_theme_color.cgColor)
      context.setLineWidth(10.0)
      context.setLineCap(.butt)

      lines.forEach { (line) in
      for(i, p) in line.enumerated(){
          //context.move(to: p)
          //context.addLine(to: p)
          if i == 0 {
              context.move(to: p)
              print("First point of new line is \(p)")
          }else{
              context.addLine(to: p)
              print("point is \(p)")
          }
      }
  }
       context.strokePath()
}

  var lines = [[CGPoint]]()

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      lines.append([CGPoint]())
      //setNeedsDisplay()
  }
  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else { return }
      guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
      lastLine.append(point)
      lines.append(lastLine)
      setNeedsDisplay()
  }

}
```

Why would the values be printing to the terminal correctly, but the lines array not actually showing the values in the view? Thanks so much in advance for your help.

I define my canvas with the following constraints :

```
    let canvas = Canvas()

    @objc fileprivate func setupCanvas(){
        //canvas.setNeedsDisplay()
        containerView.addSubview(canvas)
        canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangle2.topAnchor, constant: 74).isActive = true
        canvas.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: (view.frame.width/2) + 8).isActive = true
        canvas.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectangle2.rightAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: howitWorksText.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        canvas.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        canvas.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5
        canvas.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        //canvas.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        //canvas.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        //canvas.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        canvas.layer.masksToBounds = true
        canvas.backgroundColor = .white
        //canvas.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

and call `setupCanvas()` in my `ViewDidLoad()`

Comment: Did you give your `Canvas` a `frame` or do you have constraints that establishes it's size?  If not, then your `Canvas` view has `0` width and `0` height so it isn't visible.

Comment: I have constraints and this view is showing up as expected.

Comment: try `guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }` in `touchesMoved`.

Comment: I'm wondering if the position of the point is outside your window. Try using location(in: self) instead of location(in: nil) and see what you get

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates are off because you are using the wrong frame of reference.  Specifying `nil` for the view in [`location(in view:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-location) selects the coordinate space of the *window*.  So even though your touches are inside the canvas, your drawings are not.  You want to get the coordinates of the touch inside of the `Canvas` view by passing `self` instead of `nil` to `location(in:)`.

In `touchesMoved()` change:

```
guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else { return }
```

to:

```
guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
```

---

For more information, check out the documentation for [`location(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-location).

Comment: To add to this - converting from `nil` is the same as converting from the window coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I added that information to the answer.